# How to write the system of equations in matrix form

Tags: international-trade, simultaneous-equation-model

How to write the following equilibrium system equation as matrix from

$X_n^{j \prime}=\sum_{k=1}^J \gamma_n^{j, k} \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\pi_{i n}^{k^{\prime}}(\hat{\mathbf{w}})}{1+\tau_{i n}^{k^{\prime}}} X_i^{k^{\prime}}+\alpha_n^j\left(\widehat{w}_n w_n L_n+\sum_{j=1}^J \sum_{i=1}^N \tau_{n i}^{j^{\prime}} M_{n i}^{j^{\prime}}(\hat{\mathbf{w}})+D_n^{\prime}\right)$

This is a system of J×N equations in J×N total expenditures on p31 from this [paper](https://sites.google.com/site/lorenzocaliendo/research/CP).

I don't know how to write the system equations as $\boldsymbol{\Omega}(\hat{\mathbf{w}}) X=\Delta(\hat{\mathbf{w}})$ in this paper.